# Should a third-person limited POV reflect the personality of the POV character?

Tags: pov, third-person

I´m intending to write a fantasy story utilizing a multiple POVs in third-person limited. More than anything between the two main characters.

And I was wondering whether it's okay to make a clear differentiation depending on which character is following the narration.

Like, one of my characters is a quite serious and proper person, while the other is more easygoing, the kind that uses nicknames or shortens people's names.

So am I supposed to show that? Or should the narration in itself be neutral?

Comment: What do your favourite multiple-POV books do?

Comment: I agree, the question is a great one, but looks very similar to the one presented by Laurel